# TypeError in React, passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am getting "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.tracks.map')" in the browser, although app compiles successfully.

I checked with console.log that both SearchResults and TrackList receive props (console.log prints all elements of array within map() method) so I do not understand why the object is undefined.

Code is presented below:

File App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults.js'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="App">
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

File SearchResults.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList.js'

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

File TrackList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track.js'

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track track={track}/>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

**Update**

I also added error from the browser:

[image]

Comment: It's an issue with the way you've defined `searchResults` . The higher order function `map` is used for an array.

Comment: I tried the code live and couldn't reproduce the error... maybe you need rebuild/hot-reload your dev app?

Comment: Yeah, I've been poring over this and I can't find any overt discrepancies. Can you post a working codesandbox that repros your issue, would make debugging a bit easier.

Comment: I copied+pasted this onto my computer and didn't find any errors

Comment: @DrewReese I uploaded all files to the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/embed/old-star-rmwgo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I also attached error's screenshot to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this is happening, but when console logging `this.props.tracks` in `Tracklist` it is the defined, passed array from `SearchResults` *then* becomes `undefined`, thus causing the error you see.

**QUICK FIX** Use Guard Pattern

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { tracks } = this.props;
    console.log(tracks); // two logs, first (2)[{...}, {...}], then undefined
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {
          tracks && tracks.map((track, index) => { // Use a guard here to handle undefined tracks prop
            return <Track key={index} track={track} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In the above snippet you can simply place a guard on the `tracks` prop to defend against undefined values for the mapping. The more important question though is *why* this is occurring since the prop is never undefined here in `SearchResult`:

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('SearchResults', this.props.searchResults); // defined, only see 1 log entry
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**FURTHER INVESTIGATION**

I looked over the rest of your code and found that `App` is rendering `PlayList`, and `PlayList` **also** renders a `TrackList` but this time passes no tracks!

```
class Playlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue={'New Playlist'} />
        <TrackList /> // tracks becomes undefined here
        <button className="Playlist-save">SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION** Define Props/DefaultProps

At this point I would recommend using the react `prop-types` package to define your component's props and provide default values in some cases. Your `TrackList` component becomes:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // import proptypes
import Track from '../Track/Track.js'
import './TrackList.css'

const propTypes = {
  tracks: PropTypes.array // If you make this required (i.e. PropTypes.array.isRequired) then you'll get a react warning about missing props
};

const defaultProps = {
  tracks: [], // if tracks props is unspecified this value is used
};

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { tracks } = this.props;
    console.log(tracks);
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {
          tracks.map((track, index) => { // no longer need guard
            return <Track key={index} track={track} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TrackList.propTypes = propTypes;

TrackList.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: Thank you for help! Could you pls briefly explain why we need to pass the same props to TrackList from both SearchResults and PlayList? I used different set of data for both files and tried to use different names for props (i.e. tracks and superTracks) but nothing worked until I assigned the same prop name for both SearchResults and PlayList (prop tracks) to pass to TrackList.

Comment: React components define their API, i.e. their props. `TrackList` defines what props need to be passed to it to function, regardless of what parent component is rendering it. If it needs a `tracks` prop to be an array, then anything rendering `TrackList` needs to pass an array to its `tracks` prop, else that prop ends up being `undefined` if it isn't defined a default value.